# How to get UIView height and width in Swift? (problem: returning zero)

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, bounds, cgsize

Sorry in advance for the probably silly question - I'm a beginner

I'm generating a new UIView in viewDidLoad, providing some constraints to anchor it over the main view. When it comes to understand the size of the new view, I always get zero.

Here is a simplified version of my code which is not working:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let myView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(myView)
    myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -200).isActive = true
    myView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    myView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    print(myView.bounds.width)
    
}
```

The width (but also height) is returning 0.
This happens both with .bounds and .frame.
Do you have any hints?
Thanks!

Comment: Because the layout hasn't been done yet, so it's taking the frame you gave it, currently in `let myView = UIView(frame: .zero)`. Override viewDidLayoutSubviews, and see when it's called, and what's the frame there.

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/premature-layout/

Comment: Thank you guys - Understood. I have then an additional problem (the code I sent is simplified). I need the size of "myView" to be used to calculate the size of two UICollectionViews in ViewController. How do I manage this dependency? I.e. where do I declare the UICollections and add them as subviews: in viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question I will ask, does the UIView display on the screen?

Second, from the knowledge of [view controller life cycle](https://medium.com/good-morning-swift/ios-view-controller-life-cycle-2a0f02e74ff5), the views are laid out in viewDidLayout Subviews.

So, you want to called `myView.bounds.width` in by overriding the `viewDidLayout Subviews` or `viewDidAppear`, when the views have finally appeared in the screens

Thanks for making the question more clear.

I will suggest you either reloadData on the second collection view on viewDidLayout subviews. That way, the two gets layout as it is now, then the second collection view gets layout for the second time after the first collection view is laid.

Another approach will be for you to use relative constraints. I.e. Making weight and height constraints of the items in the second collection view relative to the items in the first collection view. This way, everything else is done automatically for you at runtime. Even if the size of the items in first collection view change later which might affect items of the second collection view, it will be taken care off.   (For accurate result if you can get it to work)

I will appreciate if you can share more of the code or screen shots of these two collections views. I could provide a better approach to creating them

Comment: Thanks for the answer - The broader problem I'm trying to solve is: I have to place two UICollectionViews on the same ViewController. Collection1 is heavier and takes time to load, but its ItemSize is needed to size the items of Collection2. When I display them on the ViewController, Collection2 gets loaded faster and the ItemSize is nil, since Collection1 is not yet created. I was trying to solve the problem through a UIView, and calculating from its size the itemSize of Collection1 before it gets started to be created. Hope it is clearer now. Whatever help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, I will suggest you asynchronies the process if possible. I will update the answer